# How do I get to a DOS prompt in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line

How do I get to a DOS prompt in Windows 7?

Comment: There is no DOS in Windows 7.

Comment: There's an important differentiation: in NT versions of windows (all the modern ones) there is no real DOS, DOS is dead. What there is the Command Interpreter, cmd.exe. The Command Interpreter emulates the functionality of DOS so that you can keep interacting with the system that way. cmd.exe is not always effective for running DOS programs (for this look in to DOSBox), and it's very outdated as a command line interface to Windows (for this use PowerShell, which is installed already in Windows 7).

Comment: But there is [Dosbox](http://www.dosbox.com/) - when cmd.exe is not enough.

Comment: There's also FAR Manager (free and open source), which is a native 32-bit/64-bit text-mode application that supports the same DOS commands that Cmd.exe does, but in a manner very similar to the famous Norton Commander that was popular among many DOS users:  http://www.farmanager.com/

Answer (score 10):

Click the Start Orb and type `cmd` in the search box, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: cmd]

This assumes that by 'DOS prompt' you are referring to a command prompt. If you want a true DOS environment then Windows 7 doesn't support this. You can however emulate DOS using [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/):

[image: DOSBox]

Comment: When I boot my computer with win 7 I get this message "TMGR is missing " I found on Internet somebody was giving this indication "at DOS prompt    .....".

Comment: So at "DOS prompt " which does not exist - perhaps ther are some diletants who don't know what they are talking about. Thanks anyway.

Comment: They might be referring to the Repair Console - it's not that they're wrong, just that there's different ways of doing that in Windows 7 now. I would recommend posting your full problem on this site as a new question and people can probably give you more direct help with your "TMGR is missing" issue.

Comment: @Michael and Gareth:  I've found that many people react "Oh, that looks like DOS!" whenever they see a text mode screen.  I suspect that much of the confusion is the result of people observing that DOS, for which many programs and applications utilize text-mode, is not graphical to the extent that MS-Windows is, wherein the overwhelming majority of programs and applications _are_ purely graphical due to being GUI-based.

Answer (score 2):

All Programs, Accessories, Command Prompt -- that's as close to a DOS box as you get, but it still takes the old DOS commands: dir, cd, etc.